# horizontal alignment of equations across multiple lines

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath

I need the following to line up so that the first line (integral) is on one line on the left at the top, then the following lines are indented and aligned to each other, but also so the 2 sets of conditions (lines starting `\left[\alpha>0,...` and `\left[\Real\mu...`) will align to be flush with the right of the page. How do I do this?

Thanks

```
\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha x}\, Y_\nu \left(\beta x\right)x^{\mu - 1}\,dx\\
= \cot v\pi\frac{\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right)^{\nu}\Gamma\left(\nu+\mu\right)}{\sqrt{\left(\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}\right)^{\nu+\mu}}\Gamma\left(\nu+1\right)}F\left(\frac{\nu+\mu}{2},\frac{\nu-\mu+1}{2};\nu+1;\frac{\beta^{2}}{\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}}\right)\\
= \mathrm{cosec}\, \nu\pi\frac{\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right)^{-\nu}\Gamma\left(\mu-v\right)}{\sqrt{\left(\alpha ^{2}+\beta^{2}\right)^{\mu-\nu}}\Gamma\left(1-\nu\right)}F\left(\frac{\mu-\nu}{2},\frac{1-\nu-\mu}{2};1-\nu;\frac{\beta^{2}}{\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}}\right)\\
\left[\Real \mu \geq\lvert \Real \nu\rvert,\quad\Real\left(\alpha\pm \textit{i}\beta\right)>0\right]\\
=-\frac{2}{\pi}\Gamma\left(\nu+\mu\right)\left(\beta^{2}+\alpha^{2}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}\mu} Q_{\mu-1}^{-\nu}\left[\alpha\left(\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}\right)^ {-\frac{1}{2}}\right]\\
\left[\alpha>0,\quad\beta>0,\quad\Real\mu>\lvert\Real \nu\rvert\right]
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please fix your example so people can see the issue, I had to guess a preamble and presumably I guessed wrong `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...+\beta ^{2}}\right )\\ \left [\Real ` It's far better if the example is complete, starting `\documentclass`...

Comment: Please state how the `\Real` macro is defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

I suppose that `\Real` means `\Re` ... The MWE for above equations is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cosec}{cosec}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \MoveEqLeft
\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha x}\, Y_\nu \left(\beta x\right)x^{\mu - 1}\,dx
                \notag  \\
    & = \cot v\pi\frac{\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right)^{\nu}
        \Gamma\left(\nu+\mu\right)}{\sqrt{\left(\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}\right)^{\nu+\mu}}
        \Gamma\left(\nu+1\right)}
    F\left(\frac{\nu+\mu}{2},\frac{\nu-\mu+1}{2};\nu+1;\frac{\beta^{2}}{\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}}\right)
                \notag  \\
    & = \cosec\, \nu\pi\frac{\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right)^{-\nu}
        \Gamma\left(\mu-v\right)}{\sqrt{\left(\alpha ^{2}+\beta^{2}\right)^{\mu-\nu}}\Gamma\left(1-\nu\right)}
        F\left(\frac{\mu-\nu}{2},\frac{1-\nu-\mu}{2};1-\nu;\frac{\beta^{2}}{\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}}\right)
                \notag  \\
\intertext{\raggedleft    
    $\left[\Re \mu \geq\lvert \Re \nu\rvert,
     \quad\Re\left(\alpha\pm \textit{i}\beta\right)>0\right]
    $}
    & =-\frac{2}{\pi}\Gamma\left(\nu+\mu\right)\left(\beta^{2}+\alpha^{2}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}\mu} 
        Q_{\mu-1}^{-\nu}\left[\alpha\left(\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}\right)^ {-\frac{1}{2}}\right]
\intertext{\raggedleft
    $\left[\alpha>0,\quad\beta>0,\quad\Re \mu>\lvert\Re \nu\rvert\right]
    $}
                \notag  
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use a combination of `equation` and `split` environments. (I wouldn't shoving the two condition lines all the way to the right.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cosec}{cosec}
\newcommand\Real{\mathfrak{R}} % is this correct?!
\usepackage{mleftright}\mleftright
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\begin{split}
&\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha x}\, Y_\nu (x)x^{\mu - 1}\,dx\\
&= \cot \nu\pi\frac{\bigl(\frac{\beta}{2}\bigr)^{\nu}\,\Gamma(\nu+\mu)}{\sqrt{(\alpha^2+\beta^2{)}^{\nu+\mu}}\,\Gamma(\nu+1)}
F\left(\frac{\nu+\mu}{2},\frac{\nu-\mu+1}{2};\nu+1;\frac{\beta^2}{\alpha^2+\beta^2}\right)\\
&= \cosec \nu\pi\frac{\bigl(\frac{\beta}{2}\bigr)^{-\nu}\,\Gamma(\mu-v)}{\sqrt{(\alpha^2+\beta^2{)}^{\mu-\nu}}\,\Gamma(1-\nu)}
F\left(\frac{\mu-\nu}{2},\frac{1-\nu-\mu}{2};1-\nu;\frac{\beta^2}{\alpha^2+\beta^2}\right)\\[1ex]
&\qquad\qquad\bigl[\Real\mu\geq\lvert \Real \nu\rvert,\ 
 \Real(\alpha\pm i\beta)>0\bigr]\\[1ex]
&=-\frac{2}{\pi} \Gamma(\nu+\mu)(\beta^2+\alpha^2{)}^{-(1/2)\mu}\, Q_{\mu-1}^{-\nu}
\bigl[\alpha(\alpha^2+\beta^2{)}^{-1/2}\,\bigr]\\[1ex]
&\qquad\qquad\bigl[\alpha>0,\ \beta>0,\ \Real\mu>\lvert\Real \nu\rvert\bigr]
\end{split}\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Till to now I wasn't aware of interesting `mleftright`  package.